# Reconnect monitor with displayport

Tags: windows-8.1, displayport

I have a Dell 2711 monitor which I connect using Displayport to either a laptop (Windows 8.1) or a desktop.  I can't use any of the other connections, since only the Displayport supports the maximum resolution (I don't have dual DVI outputs)

Whenever I reconnect the monitor to the laptop, it fails to recognize it, but if I then log off windows, it once again recognizes it and shows the login screen on the monitor.

I was thinking about getting a KVM switch, but given this behavior, it would be impossible to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the one of the Fn keys on the laptop toggles between internal and external video (e.g. projector)? That might trigger the DisplayPort monitor without having to log off.

Comment: Tried all Fn+F# combinations, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you also tried suspending or taking your laptop into hibernation, then back out?

Comment: Yes, that works, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: I think suspension is better than logging out as you don't have to close out of your work.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a BenQ BL3201PH monitor. Have you been able to get yours working properly?

Comment: No, the problem persists.  Perhaps Windows 10 will have a solution.